# How do I make words in a searchbox clickable to remove them with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox

I have a searchbox on a webpage that contains words e.g. "I have a cat"
I need to make each of these words in the searchbox clickable.
When a user clicks the word it gets removed e.g. user clicks "cat" and the word disappears leaving only "I have a" in the searchbox.

It is something like there is here on stackoverflow with tags when creating a question, they get converted to clickable tiles with an X to discard them. Can you point me in the right direction? All I seem to be able to find on the net is how to remove the content of the whole searchbox which is not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: you can use [jQuery tag-it](http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/)

Comment: view this plugin http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Answer (score 4):

Found a starting point:
https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in looking at this [jQuery Tokeninput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)